# Why my code work well in windows, but not in ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6

This code works well in windows, but when I move it to my vps (ubuntu16.04, python3.6), there is some problem.

```
import json
import time
import threading
import websocket
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

def run_in_thread(sec):
    def _wrapper(func):
        def __wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            timer = threading.Timer(sec, func, [self, *args])
            timer.start()
            self._ws.on_open = self.on_open
            self._ws.run_forever()
            return self._result
        return __wrapper
    return _wrapper

class CybexHistoryAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, ws_endp):
        self._endpoint = ws_endp
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self._ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self._endpoint,
            on_message = self.on_message,
            on_error = self.on_error,
            on_close = self.on_close)
        self._login_api_id = -1
        self._history_api_id = -1
        self._api_is_ready = False
        self._call_id = 1

    def _send_msg(self, params):
        call = {"id": self._call_id, "method": "call",
                "params": params}
        self._ws.send(json.dumps(call))
        self._call_id += 1

    def on_open(self, ws):
        self._send_msg([1, "login", ["",""]])
        self._call_id = 1

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print('Remote node send an error [{}]'.format(error))

    def on_close(self, ws):
        print('Remote node closed our connection')

    def on_message(self, ws, msg):
        print(msg)
        if self._login_api_id < 0:
            result = json.loads(msg)
            self._login_api_id = result['id']
            self._send_msg([self._login_api_id, "history", []])
        elif self._history_api_id < 0:
            result = json.loads(msg)
            self._history_api_id = result['result']
            self._api_is_ready = True
        else:
            self._result = json.loads(msg)['result']
            self._ws.close()
            self.reset()

    @run_in_thread(0.01)
    def get_account_history(self, account_id, stop, limit, start):
        while not self._api_is_ready:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        self._send_msg([self._history_api_id, "get_account_history",
            [account_id, stop, limit, start]])

    @run_in_thread(0.01)
    def get_market_history(self, base_id, quote_id, ts, start, end):
        while not self._api_is_ready:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        self._send_msg([self._history_api_id, "get_market_history",
            [base_id, quote_id, ts, start, end]])

    @run_in_thread(0.01)
    def get_fill_order_history(self, base_id, quote_id, limit):
        while not self._api_is_ready:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        self._send_msg([self._history_api_id, "get_fill_order_history",
            [base_id, quote_id, limit]])

def scan_account(acc_id, max_len = 100):
    api = CybexHistoryAPI('wss://shanghai.51nebula.com')
    start = 0
    tot_len = 0
    while tot_len < max_len:
        print('start at 1.11.{}'.format(start))
        ret = api.get_account_history(acc_id, '1.11.1', 100, '1.11.' + str(start))
        if len(ret) == 0 or int(ret[0]['id'].split('.')[-1]) == start:
            break
        tot_len += len(ret)
        print('got {}'.format(len(ret)))
        print('end at {}'.format(ret[-1]['id']))
        #print(json.dumps(ret, indent=2))
        start = int(ret[-1]['id'].split('.')[-1]) - 1

    print(tot_len)
    return

def run_test():
    scan_account('1.2.38696')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ListenTransferRecord.py", line 197, in <module>
    run_test()
File "ListenTransferRecord.py", line 186, in run_test
    respone = scan_account(accountID,10)
File "ListenTransferRecord.py", line 147, in scan_account
    ret = api.get_account_history(acc_id, '1.11.1', 100, '1.11.' + str(start))
File "ListenTransferRecord.py", line 71, in __wrapper
    return self._result
AttributeError: 'CybexHistoryAPI' object has no attribute '_result'
```

I don't understand why it can work well in windows but not in ubuntu.

And I've tried run some simple code in my VPS(ubuntu) to test if the python environment is ok.

I've tried reinstalling all the modules of this code import. 
But it is still not working.

Comment: You're setting `self._result` in your `on_message` method, is that actually firing? Is the input you're giving the same on windows?

Comment: In `on_message` you are setting `result` on two conditions. In the `else` case on the other hand your are setting `self._result`.

Comment: yes, total same code. without changing anything. I just copy this code to ubuntu and run.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get just happens to trigger a bug that was *already* there - `self._result` is only set on a specific condition (in the `else` branch in the `on_message` method) but you unconditionnally access it in your decorator. For some reason (which we can't tell without much more details - actually chances are no one can tell without testing the code in your exact environment) you never (so far) stumbled on this case when running the code on Window, but the bug itself isn't dependent of the environment itself. The fix here is quite simple: just make sure the `_result` attribute is *always* set (eventually to some sentinel value like `None`:

```
def on_message(self, ws, msg):
    print(msg)

    self._result = None # default value

    if self._login_api_id < 0:
        result = json.loads(msg)
        self._login_api_id = result['id']
        self._send_msg([self._login_api_id, "history", []])
    elif self._history_api_id < 0:
        result = json.loads(msg)
        self._history_api_id = result['result']
        self._api_is_ready = True
    else:
        self._result = json.loads(msg)['result']
        self._ws.close()
        self.reset()
```

As to why you have different behaviour on different environment, this can come from so many reasons that one can't be sure to list them all... it might come from network latency and synchronisation issues between your threads, OS specific implementation details, phase of the moon, whatever, and as I said those are mostly the kind of issues that can be just impossible to troubleshout without direct access to both your environments.

Comment: Although just one condiction are setting, but i think the logic is no problem. The thread is terminated just while "_ws.close（)" function is runing in the "else" condiction in function "one_massage". And at that monent, "_result" is assignment. Other condition in "one_massage", the theard is still runing, so "run_in_thread" function wouldn't return anything

Comment: Well, the error you get is an evidence that there IS a logical error (race condition, whatever), whatever you may think. Concurrent programming is always tricky...

Comment: I add "return None" in all condition. but still the same error.

Comment: Have you seen the snippet I posted??? It's not about returning None, it's about making sure the attribute is set. Returning None will of course bot fix this...

Comment: although i give all the condition with "self._return = 'thingStr'", it still error:no attribute '_result'.  It mean the function "run_in_thread" doesn't get anything from websocket.   I debug this code in ubuntu, and find that the main thread stop in “_ws.run_forever()”， and never jump to "on_open" function. then report error.

Comment: I do some test. And find that there are some problem of function:"run_forever".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100975/why-the-function-doesnt-work-in-linux-but-its-ok-in-windows-function-websoc

Comment: OK. Find out the reasion. Just because the version different of websockt. If somebody has the same comfuse like me, you can click the link above.