# Websocket code works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, websocket, python-3.6

I'm running the same code; the following works in Windows, but will run correctly on Ubuntu (16.04).

```
import websocket
import json

class WhatEver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            'wss://beijing.51nebula.com/',
            on_message=self.on_ws_message,
            on_open=self.on_open
        )

    def rin_forever(self):
        print("start run forever")
        self.ws.run_forever()


    def on_ws_message(self, ws,message):
        print (message)
        self.ws.close()

    def _send_msg(self, params):
        call = {"id": 1, "method": "call",
                "params": params}
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(call))

    def on_open(self, ws):
        print("start open function")
        self._send_msg([1, "login", ["",""]])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ws=WhatEver()
    print("start")
    ws.rin_forever()
    print("close")
```

I've tried to reinstalled all modules (including the same version of Python and `websocket` between both Windows and Ubuntu), the print of this code is correct on the Windows system:

```
start
start run forever
start open function
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":true}
close
```

But when it run in Ubuntu, while it does print, it misses some print statements:

```
start
start run forever
close
```

When I debug the code in Ubuntu, I found that the main thread stops in the `self.ws.run_forever()` call and never jumps to the `on_open` function. Then it breaks out.

Comment: Also, what library are you using? [`websocket-client`](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different versions of the library, with the version on Windows being older than version 0.53. As of version 0.53, the `websocket` project differentiates callback behaviour between *bound methods* and *regular functions*.

You are passing in bound methods (`self.on_open` and `self.on_ws_message`), at which point the `ws` argument is **not passed in**. Those methods are apparently expected to have access to the websocket already via their instance, probably because the expected use-case is to [create a subclass from the socket class](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/pull/442/files).

This is unfortunately not documented by the project, and the change [appears to have been causing problems for more people](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/commit/efcf31b30122e05701fb3f696b029baf8faa6d8e#commitcomment-30457750).

So for version 0.53 and newer, drop the `ws` argument from your callbacks:

```
class WhatEver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            'wss://beijing.51nebula.com/',
            on_message=self.on_ws_message,
            on_open=self.on_open
        )


    # ...

    def on_ws_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        self.ws.close()

    # ...

    def on_open(self):
        print("start open function")
        self._send_msg([1, "login", ["", ""]])
```

And you can discover issues like these by enabling logging; the `websocket` module logs exceptions it encounters in callbacks to the `logger.getLogger('websocket')` logger. A quick way to see these issues is to enable tracing:

```
websocket.enableTrace(True)
```

which adds a logging handler just to that logging object, turns on `logging.DEBUG` level reporting for that object and in addition enables full socket data echoing.

Or you can configure logging to output messages in general with the [`logging.basicConfig()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
```

which lets you see `logging.ERROR` level messages and up.

With using the latter option, the uncorrected version of the code prints out:

```
start
start run forever
ERROR:websocket:error from callback <bound method WhatEver.on_open of <__main__.WhatEver object at 0x1119ec668>>: on_open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ws'
close
```

You can verify the version of `websocket-client` you have installed by printing `websocket.__version__`:

```
>>> import websocket
>>> websocket.__version__
'0.54.0'
```

Comment: Thank you! This problem trobule me for a week...Just cause the version of websocket.